# RShiny dynamic Popup (can move)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I work on a dashboard and I would like to create a dynamic popup , ie we can move.
I can create a pop-up but this one is static, I like that one can take it and move it to the right, left ...

A example of my pop up :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

shinyApp(

  ui =
    fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        box(actionButton("tabBut", "View Table")),
        mainPanel(
          bsModal("modalExample", "Data Table", "tabBut", size = "large",
                  dataTableOutput("distTable"))))),

  server =
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$distTable <- renderDataTable({
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = 30 + 1)
        tab <- hist(x, breaks = bins, plot = FALSE)
        tab$breaks <- sapply(seq(length(tab$breaks) - 1), function(i) {
          paste0(signif(tab$breaks[i], 3), "-", signif(tab$breaks[i+1],    3))})
        tab <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, tab))
        colnames(tab) <- c("Bins", "Counts", "Density")
        return(tab[, 1:3])}, 
        options = list(pageLength=10))}
)
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ykMg.png)

And I want that the user can move this window.
If you have ideas of option to change, or so if you know any means other than BS Shiny on to create new window...

Thank you in advance and sorry for my English !

Comment: Check out the [superzip example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html) to see how they used `absolutePanel`, which allows you to add `draggable=T`. Should give you what you're looking for with minimal effort.

Comment: Thank you indeed absolutePanel also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do it manyally :

1) Add script

2) add draggable

3) edit css

like:

```
 ui =
    fluidPage(
      tags$head(HTML('<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
                    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>')),
        tags$script(HTML('  $(window).load(function(){
                        $("#modalExample").draggable({
                        handle: ".modal-header"
                                   });
                                   });')),
            tags$style(HTML("
            .modal-backdrop.in {
                opacity: 0;
            }    
                ")),
      sidebarLayout(
        box(actionButton("tabBut", "View Table")),
        mainPanel(

          bsModal("modalExample", "Data Table", "tabBut", size = "large",
                  dataTableOutput("distTable")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the shinyjqui package. For an example script see:

https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1698

Change:

jqui_draggable(selector = '.modal-content')

into:

jqui_draggable(ui = '.modal-content')